# How to overcome my ISP router limitations (1Gbps ports on 2Gbps connection)?

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, isp

Here is my problem :

I recently switched to the quickest ISP available in my region : Orange.

It offers **2Gb/s FTTH** internet connection, but the crappy provided router 'Livebox 5' only has 4 gigabit ethernet LAN ports and WiFi... so on a basic installation, i can only have a **1Gb/s access per machine** directly connected to it !

I was able to confirm it's an "Integrated switch" limitation by connecting two computers to their router and downloading at 1Gb/s on both of them at the same time...

I also managed to get to 2Gb/s on a single Win10 machine by connecting two gigabit network cards directly to their router and using "Connectify Dispatch PRO" software to aggregate these links !

I also figured out that the ISP router integrated switch don't supports 802.3ad (LACP) aggregation...

As i have some 10Gb/s SFP+ machines, i wonder how i can arrange my network to allow full 2Gb/s download speed on these machines ?

Here is what i have on hand :
- the crappy 'Livebox 5' ISP router with 4 Gigabit ports

- **TP-Link T1700G-28TQ** L3 Smart Switch with 24 Gigabit slots and 4 10GE SFP+ Slots
- a Win10 PC with 1Gb/s integrated card and a 10Gb/s SFP+ network card
- two Debian servers with 1Gb/s integrated cards and a 10Gb/s SFP+ network cards
- lots of 1Gb/s Win10 and Debian machines...
- lots of RasPi's

Please give me some hints on where to start !

Thx a lot guys !

Comment: What physical connection does your Livebox use on the WAN side?

Comment: it uses Monomode SC/APC

Comment: Link Aggregation doesn’t do what you (probably) think anyway. It doesn’t allow for a single 2 Gb/s stream (TCP/UDP/whatever) over two 1 Gb/s links.

Comment: @DanielB "Connectify Dispatch PRO" works perfectly, but I don't know how !

Comment: @A.B ONT is integrated with this Livebox 5, so no way...

Comment: Connectify uses at least one stream per network link. These streams are “independent” between the software and Connectify’s remote services.

Comment: Connectify Dispatch don't uses any remote service, it's only a local load-balancing proxy, don't confuse with Connectify Speedify who is VPN with Channel Bonding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to do it ! 
I just had to put a pfSense router between my LAN and my ISP router !

pfSense has two Gigabit links as WAN to the ISP router, and one SFP+ link to my LAN, then :

- Checked "Use non-local gateway" on each WAN gateway
- Made a "Gateway group" with both WAN gateways
- Chose this Gateway group as the Gateway in the LAN firewall rule

And voila ! 
https://www.speedtest.net/result/d/06b049fe-4fdf-4952-8efb-c65aa79503dd

[image]

Comment: Which WAN gateways did you put in your gateway group?

Comment: @PsY4 quelle modèle t a utilisé?

Comment: Could you please upload some more information about wan interface configuration? Did you use DHCP? Does ipv6 work?